# Freeswitch can't connect to external sip profile on server

Tags: android, voip, freeswitch, pbx, fusionpbx

I am using port `5060` set on internal profile while the external has `5080`.I have created extensions on the server.

I want user to connect sip server using the external profile defined in `external.xml` i.e

`ext_no@XX.YY.ZZ.PP:5080`.It says

> 2013-12-06 05:48:28.740200 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2454 Can't find user [ext_no@XX.YY.ZZ.PP] You must define a domain called '`XX.YY.ZZ.PP`' in your directory and
>   add a user with the id="`ext_no`" attribute  and you must configure your
>   device to use the proper domain in it's authentication credentials.

While it can successfully connect using internal sip profile by just changing the port no,i.e with sip URI:

`ext_no@XX.YY.ZZ.PP:5060` and says:

> [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:1432 SIP auth challenge (REGISTER) on sofia
>   profile 'internal' for [ext_no@XX.YY.ZZ.PP] from ip 1.23.169.192

I am on FusionPBX
Please guide.Thanks

Note:i have a valid ext_no and sip uri.Just did not disclose it for security.

*To those who voted to close:*

`This is related to Voip which requires the sip connection to be established between mobile device and server`.

Answer (score 0):

The external SIP profile is anonymous and doesn't handle registrations. You would likely want to make a copy of the internal profile say internal-5070 as an example and set the port to 5070. Set the new internal-5070 sip profile with the external sip and rtp IP to use the external IP address. Open up iptables on the local server for SIP port 5070 TCP/UDP and then register the SIP phone to 5070.